# ScrollView is Not working in Layout

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/sw_ManualRefresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Today"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.7dp"
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView5"
            />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_Today_plan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/list_Upcoming_plans"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/list_Upcoming_plans" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upcoming"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_Today_plan"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view2" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView6"
            />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/list_Upcoming_plans"
            android:layout_below="@id/view2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: This is my screen]

Screen is not scrolling. The screen contains Swipe refresh also. 
I have tried different solutions and added this line

> `android:fillViewport="true"`
>   and removed orientation for relative layout.

Why scroll view not working here?

But screen is not scrolling. I am new to android.

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: try to use Recycyerview instead of ListView then scrollView will work perfectly.

Comment: because `scrollView` and `swipeRefresh` will slide up and down conflict,you need solve confict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Use **`NestedScrollView`** and **`RecyclerView`** instead of **`ScrollView`** and **`LIstView`**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/sw_ManualRefresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Today"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1.7dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView5"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/list_Today_plan"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Upcoming"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1.7dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"

                    />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**[here is link for migrate from ListView to RecyclerView](https://traversoft.com/2016/01/31/replace-listview-with-recyclerview/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should put `ScrollView` inside of `widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/garae_scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

//Your Scrollview content and other layouts here


</ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: it is not a answer as OP need refresh content inside scrollView not outside